# Field readonly and groups attribute

Tags: odoo

I wish to make a field readonly in Openerp 6.1 views.

I want the field to be readonly for all groups but specific groups, let's say manager should be able to edit it while others should be able to only view.

I am not clear how to do it in a view ? Please suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to share more information about wht model(module ) and what view are we talking about.

It its a base module then the only way might be to inherit it and then make changes.

You can try the below short cut but I am not sure if it will work out for you.

go to Settings >> Customization >> Database Structure >> Fields >>

There find the field and model you want to change and then in security change it.

[image]

Comment: i tried this but getting the error "Properties of base fields cannot be altered in this manner! Please modify them through Python code, preferably through a custom addon!" .   

The field is x_mktg_id I added by inheriting the crm.lead model.

Comment: @helloworld sorry I ran out of ideas. You will need to code this.

Comment: thanks, I found some relevant links:
in openerp forum: http://www.openerp.com/forum/topic24183.html?sid=7f519c15835c7dc9c8ca6a9bd4f605dc
and launchpad https://answers.launchpad.net/openobject-server/+question/178779

Answer (score 4):

You just create a [functional field](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_2.html#functional-fields) in your model which will be true if the user belong to manager group else false, then add [`attrs`](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_6_views_events/views/design_element.html#field) for your field so that it will be editable if the user belong to manager group or else readonly.

or you can try this method:

```
'your_field_name': fields.char(
    'Customer Reference',
    size=64,
    write=['base.group_partner_manager'],
    read=['base.group_user'],
    ),
```

You can find this in https://answers.launchpad.net/openobject-server/+question/178779

Answer (score 0):

OpenERP provide a facility to apply a restriction to specific group by accessright.
let's take simple example if you have two group user and manager for model project.project and you allow that user can only read project and manager can read,write,update,delete a project.create two group user and manager and give rights you want to give.
now apply this group on your field in xml for eg.groups="project.group_project_user"

Comment: He is not talking of whole object! the field itself can be reference to an object or just some native fields like 'float', 'char' etc. I agree with @vishal.