# Openerp: How can I change in base field properties using Administration menu?

Tags: python, odoo

How can I change in base field properties using `Administration>customization>database structure->fields`?

While trying to do this, I get this error "Properties of base fields cannot be altered in this manner! Please modify them through Python code, preferably through a custom addon!
"

Comment: Doesn't that sort of explicitly state you can't?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580150/field-readonly-and-groups-attribute The unaccepted answer might be relevant to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't use that screen to change base fields, because their properties are defined in Python code. That screen is used to add custom fields and edit them. If you want to change base fields, you have to [write a module](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_1.html) that inherits and modifies the field, or hack on the core module's source code to change the properties. Inheriting the module is recommended because it makes migrating to future versions easier.